# flutter widget InteractiveViewer inside Scaffold body

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I have `InteractiveViewer` inside Scaffold, and inside them one time I have landscape images, another time portrait image. But dimensions of `InteractiveViewer` always have dimension like on page startup. How to allow to display image inside `InteractiveViewer` on whole body?
Here is code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body:Center( child: InteractiveViewer(
          boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          maxScale: 5.0,
          child: FlutterLogo(size: 100),
        ),),)
      
    );
  }
}
```

output when I resize object inside `InteractiveViewer` with fingers:
[image]
but I expect:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `clipBehavior: Clip.none,` But the view depend on inner size. Also can be experiment on  `constrained: false`

```dart
 InteractiveViewer(
    boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    maxScale: 5.0,
    child: FlutterLogo(size: 100)),
```

But the child has to be bigger for `InteractiveViewer`

```dart
body: Center(
  child: InteractiveViewer(
    boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
    maxScale: 5.0,
    minScale: 1,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 500, // this
      height: 500,
      child: Center(child: FlutterLogo(size: 100)),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank You, I just add `clipBehavior: Clip.none,` inside `InteractiveViewer` and it working!